# ASP.NET @html actionlink with no hover text

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I hope this is an easy question.  I have some @Html.ActionLink in my navbar that when I hover over them the browser displays a little tooltip that gives the page name.  I do NOT want this to happen.  Its probably bad practice to take this default functionality out but I need to.  I don't know where or how to do this though.

Comment: could you give the generated html ? And which browser shows this tooltip ? And complete ActionLink code, too, by the way ?

Comment: The toolip comes from the `title` attribute, but `Html.ActionLink` does not add a `title` attribute by default. Most likely, this is browser functionality, that you cannot control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test this right now, but the tooltip is coming from the `title` attribute, you should be able to empty that out like:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { title="" })
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps a jQuery solution:

```
$('a').attr('title', '');
```

Comment: Tried this...but to no avail.  I think Chris Pratt is correct that this is a browser function that I cannot control.  I placed my navbar at the bottom of the page but when you hover over the action links the little tooltip thing pops up and it covers some of the navbar which sucks.  I think I will just have to deal with it.

Comment: Hmm, ok, how about the jQuery solution I just added?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Button Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { para_name = param_value} , new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-sm", @title="text you want to see when hovering" });
```

Comment: You are replying to a post which is 4 years old.  If you have something new to add please add an explanation to your answer which add something new to the discussion.